# LinearLayoutICS ignore showDivider:end attribute

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using LinearLayoutICS because i would like to handle form items margins like the following tutorial:

http://cyrilmottier.com/2014/11/17/grid-spacing-on-android/

This tutorial sets the container items margins using LinearLayout dividers with a 'fake' gap drawable. 
In API > 14 works using a simple LinearLayout, but if you want back-compatibility to API, is neccessary use LinearLayoutICS.

The problem is that 'showDivider:end' layout attribute is totally ignored using LinearLayoutICS.

```
     <android.support.v7.internal.widget.LinearLayoutICS
        style="@style/Form.Field.Container"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        divider="@drawable/form_item_separator"
        showDividers="middle|beginning|end"
        />
```

Someone knows some workaround for this situation? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post the style code?

If you are using wrap_content is possible that the LinearLayout is ending before the divider appear

Answer (score 1):

Quite so! I was using layout_height with wrap_content constraint, I've changed to match parent and it works!!

WRONG

```
 <style name="Form.Field.Container">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/form_container_padding_left</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/form_container_padding_right</item>
        <item name="divider">@drawable/form_item_separator</item>
        <item name="showDividers">middle|beginning|end</item>
    </style>
```

SOLUTION

```
    <style name="Form.Field.Container">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/form_container_padding_left</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/form_container_padding_right</item>
        <item name="divider">@drawable/form_item_separator</item>
        <item name="showDividers">middle|beginning|end</item>
    </style>
```

Thanks!!